# Generate unique id with 6 of length

Tags: logic, unique

I need to generate a unique id with a limit of 6 blocks. That id **should** contains **letters in upper case** and **number**.

How can I do it? I thougth in use the date, but I'm failed.

More details...

That Id just need not repeat, but should be generate alone, whithout base in a last sequence.
I can do this in any language.

Comment: What language are you trying to program this in? Could you not just use the unique portion of a GUID?

Comment: What are the requirements of this unique id? Can you simply work through the set {000000, 000001,..., 00000A, ..., ZZZZZZ}?

Answer (score 0):

I made a blog post to generate a strong SQL Server password. You can adapt this to what you need.  For a better format blog post [here.](http://blog.digitaltools.com/post/2011/08/19/Generating-Passwords.aspx)

We have the requirement that our passwords have to change every 90 days.  I wanted to automate this and it sounded pretty easy to do, but it wasn’t that easy.  Why? Because there are a lot of rules for passwords.

First, I have to store it in the web.config.  So no XML special characters.

```
quot " 
amp & 
apos ' 
lt < 
gt >
```

Next, If used in an OLE DB or ODBC connection string, a password must not contain the following characters: [] {}() , ; ? * ! @.

Finally, strong passwords must contains characters from at least three of the following categories:

```
English uppercase characters (A through Z)
English lowercase characters (a through z)
Base 10 digits (0 through 9) 
Nonalphabetic characters (for example: !, $, #, %)
```

So keeping all of these rules in mind I created a simple class. that I can just call

```
public class PasswordGenerator
{
    private static string CHARS_LCASE = "abcdefgijkmnopqrstwxyz";
    private static string CHARS_UCASE = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTWXYZ";
    private static string CHARS_NUMERIC = "23456789";
    private static string CHARS_SPECIAL = "*-+_%/";
    private static string CHARS_ALL = CHARS_LCASE + CHARS_UCASE + CHARS_NUMERIC + CHARS_SPECIAL;

    public static string GeneratePassword(int length)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[length];
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    chars[i] = CHARS_LCASE[rand.Next(0, CHARS_LCASE.Length)];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    chars[i] = CHARS_UCASE[rand.Next(0, CHARS_UCASE.Length)];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    chars[i] = CHARS_NUMERIC[rand.Next(0, CHARS_NUMERIC.Length)];
                    break;
                case 3:
                    chars[i] = CHARS_SPECIAL[rand.Next(0, CHARS_SPECIAL.Length)];
                    break;

                default:
                    chars[i] = CHARS_ALL[rand.Next(0, CHARS_ALL.Length)];
                    break;
            }
        }

        return new string(chars);
    }
}
```

So now I just simply call this for a new password:

PasswordGenerator.GeneratePassword(13)